# Combine didSelectRowAt with prepareForSegue?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I would like to differentiate what is being sent via prepareForSegue.

For instance; if the top cell in the tableView (`indexPath.row == 0`) I would like to send over firstVariable, and if `indexPath.row == 1` I would like to send over secondVariable, and so on.

I have tried this without luck:

```
   let starterInfoSegueIdentifier = "ToStarterInfoSegue"

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
             func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
            {
                if segue.identifier == starterInfoSegueIdentifier
                {
                    let destination = segue.destination as! Starter2ViewController
                    let starterIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
                    destination.name = startersArray[starterIndex!]
                    destination.variable = firstVariable
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Here is updated code:

```
class StartersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let startersArray = ["ArrayItem1", "ArrayItem2"]


    var firstVariable = 1
    var secondVariable = 10

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return startersArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StartersCell") as! StartersTableViewCell

        //Set round corners
        cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.layer.frame.height / 2

        cell.startersLabel.text = startersArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



        let starterInfoSegueIdentifier = "ToStarterInfoSegue"

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier:starterInfoSegueIdentifier,sender:indexPath.row)
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == starterInfoSegueIdentifier
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! Starter2ViewController
            let index = sender as! Int
            destination.name = startersArray[index]
            destination.counter =  index == 0 ? firstVariable : secondVariable

        }

    }

}
```

The code for the `tableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class StartersTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var startersLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prepare has to be class scope

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:starterInfoSegueIdentifier,sender:indexPath.row)
}
```

//

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
        if segue.identifier == starterInfoSegueIdentifier
        {
             let destination = segue.destination as! Starter2ViewController
             let index = sender as! Int 
              destination.name = startersArray[index]
              destination.variable =  index == 0 ? firstVariable : secondVariable

         }

}
```

If you have many variables then i suggest creating a `struct` to contain your model then add it's objects inside `startersArray` and access from the properties of the struct's object

```
struct MyContent {
    var name:String
    var otherVar:String
}
```

then refactor to this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:starterInfoSegueIdentifier,sender:startersArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

//

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
        if segue.identifier == starterInfoSegueIdentifier
        {
             let destination = segue.destination as! Starter2ViewController
             let item = sender as! MyContent
              destination.name = item.name
              destination.variable = item.otherVar

         }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting the following error when pushing any of the cells in the tableview: ` Could not cast value of type `TabBarMenu1.StartersTableViewCell' (0x103392010) to 'NSNumber' `  Any idea why?

Comment: you send the cell itself not it's content attach the code so i can help you

Comment: Sorry.. This line: `let index = sender as! Int`

Comment: this line has no thing to do with the error , it casts int to int perfectly , do you call performSegue anywhere else , please attach whole code

Comment: Hmm. That's the line Xcode points to. The code after the edit in my question is the whole code actually. I have also attached the code for the `tableViewCell` The whole error message is: `Could not cast value of type 'TabBarMenu1.StartersTableViewCell' (0x108d8b008) to 'NSNumber' (0x10943fb40).
2018-06-08 07:28:09.252515+0200 TabBarMenu1[1860:23733] Could not cast value of type 'TabBarMenu1.StartersTableViewCell' (0x108d8b008) to 'NSNumber' (0x10943fb40).`

Answer (score 0):

I see in question as well as the answer the indexPath or indexPath.row is passed as Any parameter of the performSegue(withIdentifier) function.

I believe the simple approach would be to define class variable, say startersArrayIndexToPass, to store index of item to be passed. Store this variable in tableview(didSelectRowAt) method and use in prepare(segue:) function. This approach avoids converting known type to Any and then casting back from Any to know type.